# JqueryMobile- event for page become active

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using PhoneGap with jQueryMobile to develop my application. I want to refresh data when the app is running at background and is going to visible. I listen to "pageshow" event but It just was fired when the app initialize only ( starting time). I also looked at [this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) but I can't find any event for page visibility. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. I use "resume" event of Phonegap to handle this case.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `pagebeforeshow`. It'll fired before showing the page on the screen. So behind the screen you can load the data and show it to user.

[Read about pagebeforeshow here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/)

Sample code

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#mypage', function(){
    alert('fire before showing page')
});
```

Here is a live working example at fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/Mcb4s/

Comment: This event just be call 1 time when the page is create. When user press button Home the app run at background, then open the app again, this event isn't called.

Comment: Pagecreate is fired only one time. But as far I as I remember `pageshow` and `pagebefore` should fire every time you load the page. I've  used multiple times on my projects. Can you cross check again plz.